# How to Open Housing to Replace Light Bulb?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I need to replace a light bulb, the problem is I have no idea how to open the housing as it has no screws or anything visible where I could open it from. Here is a photo, any idea how I could open it?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How big is this? Have you tried getting your fingernails behind the bezel and pulling?

Comment: You may want to check out this question. Your light fixture looks almost identical to the one there.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/153155/7367

Comment: You have two options: pull or turn (usually counterclockwise).

Comment: @isherwood Pull or turn from the glass or bezel?

Comment: The glass. The bezel is probably part of the base, which is screwed to the electrical box. Normally things in contact with the ceiling don't move or they'd scar up the paint.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar fixture, and it uses a spring loaded set of three clips.  Simply pull on the cover.  But for the ones I have the force is scary high for a thin diffuser.

I also have a similar fixture and the dome has three bayonet tabs which will disengage with about a 1/8 turn.  This one is a bit older, and the diffuser is heavier than the one mentioned above.

Those are common fastenings, but there is no assurance that they are what you have.  If you know your manufacturer/model, you might find info with a product search.